# How to pass 64-bit value in vxworks shell

Tags: vxworks

How would you pass a 64-bit value to a function in the vxworks console?

For instance this works:

```
[C INTERP]->tickSet 0x1fffff
value = 2097151 = 0x1fffff
```

Whereas this:

```
[C INTERP]->tick64Set 0xfffffffff
C interp: '0xfffffffff' is not a valid integer value.
```

Doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add 'ull' to denote that it is an unsigned-long-long:

```
-> 0xfffffffff   
C interp: '0xfffffffff' is not a valid integer value.
-> 0xfffffffffull
value = 68719476735 = 0xfffffffff
->
```

Comment: Cheers. Thats almost there, although the return value from said function call still doesnt look quite right. I am assuming this is probably just the shell not handling it correctly: `->tick64Set 0x123456789ull
value = 591751049 = 0x23456789` - it appears to have chopped off the Most Significant Byte.

Comment: Yes, the shell is truncating the return. You can tell the correct parameters have been passed by running this function `void printTickLib()
{
    UINT64 tick64=0;
    ULONG tick32=0;

    tick64=tick64Get();
    tick32=tickGet();

    printf("Tick 64 %llu (0x%llx) Tick32 %lu (0x%0x)\n", tick64,tick64, tick32,tick32);
}
`